# How to avoid divide by zero error here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, divide-by-zero

The following query that I have is encountering a divide by 0 error:

```
select  pp.building_name, 
        ld.tenant_trading_name,  
        tenancy_reference,  
        ld.turnover_threshold, 
        ld.percentage_rent, 
        ld.income_base_rent_ach, 
        ld.income_base_rent_ach / ld.percentage_rent as correct 
from 
    lease_deal.lease ld

inner join property.property pp
    on ld.building_id = pp.building_id

where 
    (ld.income_base_rent_ach / ld.percentage_rent ) <> ld.turnover_threshold
    and lease_status = 'APPROVED'
    and ld.progenesis_load_date is  null
order by pp.building_name
```

I've tried to correct this by doing the following - but I'm receiving a syntax error and I'm unsure why? What is syntactically incorrect here?

```
select  pp.building_name, 
        ld.tenant_trading_name,  
        tenancy_reference,  
        ld.turnover_threshold, 
        ld.percentage_rent, 
        ld.income_base_rent_ach, 
        ld.income_base_rent_ach / ld.percentage_rent as correct 
from 
    lease_deal.lease ld

inner join property.property pp
    on ld.building_id = pp.building_id

where 
    case when ld.percentage_rent = 0
    then 1=1
    else ((ld.income_base_rent_ach / ld.percentage_rent ) <> ld.turnover_threshold)
    end
    and lease_status = 'APPROVED'
    and ld.progenesis_load_date is  null
order by pp.building_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about replacing

```
(ld.income_base_rent_ach / ld.percentage_rent ) <> ld.turnover_threshold
```

with

```
ld.income_base_rent_ach <> (ld.percentage_rent * ld.turnover_threshold)
```

Comment: Excellent. Any thoughts as to why I was getting the syntax error also (educational curiosity)

Comment: You were dividing by zero.  Doug removed that possibility by changing it to a multiplication (where zero is no problem).  My answer was an attempt at sanely checking for 0 and using lazy evaluation to make sure it never divides by zero.

Comment: Just to clarify: you can't rely on lazy evaluation or short circuiting, since you can't ever be certain that given `x or y` SQL Server will evaluate `x` first - see [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no) for examples of cases where short circuiting does NOT work because of this very thing: SQL Server does not make any guarantees about left-to-right evaluation, even in cases (no pun intended) where the documentation *does* lead you to believe this guarantee exists.